# How to Disable Flutter Inspector Guidelines Permanently?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

[these are the lines i am getting and these are annoying, i have to disable them after every reload manually.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QTx5.png)[this is getting enable on every reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du79y.png)

I just took this code from my teammate through github and he was also facing this issue, but he was working on mobile side and he have to disable it for one time only after restart, but i have to disable this on every reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have this code somewhere in your project:

```dart
debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
```

You can remove it to disable the guidelines.

---

See also:

- [Show guidelines](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector#show-guidelines)

Comment: yes i do have this

Comment: void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Comment: Set it to `false`, or remove it

Comment: i removed it, it worked. thanks buddy.